# php get static url and get section of url

Tags: php

How do you get the routed url that is static, when I use $_SERVER["PHPSELF"] it returns that actual page of the url like for e.g

```
/show_products.php
```

but the url I have is this

```
http://mysite.com/browse/department/?pid=1&order_by=a_z&filter=1
```

what I want to get from the url is just this

```
 http://mysite.com/browse/department/
```

and also I would like to be able to just get the department section of the url so there is two parts to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL scheme and hostname part must be handled individually from the request URI:

```
// in your example, this results in "http://"
$scheme = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] <> 'off') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
// in your example, this results in "mysite.com"
$hostname = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
// in your example, this results in "/browse/department/"
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Putting the pieces together:

```
// in your example, this results in "http://mysite.com/browse/department/"
echo $scheme . $hostname . $uri;
```

Read more about the various values inside the [`$_SERVER[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array, or just output [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) to easily search the `$_SERVER[]` array for the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get "The URI which was given in order to access this page" [per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Note that REQUEST_URI does not include the hostname, you'd need to stitch in $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].

Then php's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) may be the easiest way to give you the different pieces, and quickly drill down to what you want. Once you have the path from the url (/browse/department) you can explode on "/" to get the individual path pieces.

See here: http://3v4l.org/6ssAI